# Given the following XML in SQL Server, how do I get a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

Here is my SQL. I cannot seem to get one single value out of this thing. It only works if I remove all of the xmlns attributes.

I think the problem is that this xml contains 2 default namespaces, one attached to the Response element and one attached to the Shipment element.

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = '<TrackResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Response xmlns="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
    <ResponseStatus>
      <Code>1</Code>
      <Description>Success</Description>
    </ResponseStatus>
    <TransactionReference />
  </Response>
  <Shipment xmlns="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0">
    <InquiryNumber>
      <Code>01</Code>
      <Description>ShipmentIdentificationNumber</Description>
      <Value>1ZA50209234098230</Value>
    </InquiryNumber>
    <ShipperNumber>A332098</ShipperNumber>
    <ShipmentAddress>
      <Type>
        <Code>01</Code>
        <Description>Shipper Address</Description>
      </Type>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>123 HWY X</AddressLine>
        <City>SOMETOWN</City>
        <StateProvinceCode>SW</StateProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>20291   1234</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </ShipmentAddress>
    <ShipmentWeight>
      <UnitOfMeasurement>
        <Code>LBS</Code>
      </UnitOfMeasurement>
      <Weight>0.00</Weight>
    </ShipmentWeight>
    <Service>
      <Code>42</Code>
      <Description>UPS GROUND</Description>
    </Service>
    <Package>
      <TrackingNumber>1ZA50209234098230</TrackingNumber>
      <PackageServiceOption>
        <Type>
          <Code>01</Code>
          <Description>Signature Required</Description>
        </Type>
      </PackageServiceOption>
      <Activity>
        <ActivityLocation>
          <Address>
            <City>SOMEWHERE</City>
            <StateProvinceCode>PA</StateProvinceCode>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          </Address>
        </ActivityLocation>
        <Status>
          <Type>X</Type>
          <Description>Damage reported. / Damage claim under investigation.</Description>
          <Code>UY</Code>
        </Status>
        <Date>20120424</Date>
        <Time>125000</Time>
      </Activity>
      <Activity>
        <ActivityLocation>
          <Address>
            <City>SOMEWHERE</City>
            <StateProvinceCode>PA</StateProvinceCode>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          </Address>
        </ActivityLocation>
        <Status>
          <Type>X</Type>
          <Description>All merchandise discarded. UPS will notify the sender with details of the damage.</Description>
          <Code>GY</Code>
        </Status>
        <Date>20120423</Date>
        <Time>115500</Time>
      </Activity>
      <PackageWeight>
        <UnitOfMeasurement>
          <Code>LBS</Code>
        </UnitOfMeasurement>
        <Weight>0.00</Weight>
      </PackageWeight>
    </Package>
  </Shipment>
</TrackResponse>'

select Svc.Dsc.value('(/TrackResponse/Shipment/Service/Description)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
from @xml.nodes('/TrackResponse') as Svc(Dsc)
```

Comment: What element(s) are you trying to obtain the values for specifically?

Comment: I would like the text of /TrackResponse/Shipment/Service/Description

Comment: I really need the LAST Activity element's status type text (/TrackResponse/Shipment/Package/Activity[2]/Status/Type in this case) but I really just want to understand how to specify the namespaces properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- you're blatantly ignoring the XML namespace that's defined on the `<shipment>` element
- your XQuery expression was a bit off

Try this:

```
-- define XML namespace
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0' AS ns)
select 
    Svc.Dsc.value('(ns:Shipment/ns:Service/ns:Description)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
from 
    -- this already selects all <TrackResponse> nodes - no need to repeat that in 
    -- your above call to .value()
    @xml.nodes('/TrackResponse') as Svc(Dsc)
```

Gives me a result of:

```
UPS GROUND
```

Answer (score 3):

As @marc_s said, you are ignoring xml namespaces. [Here is a sql fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7345). This gives **X**, I think that is what you need. [Read this article for more](http://blog.jontav.com/post/11396385355/ignore-xml-namespaces-in-t-sql). Note : `*:TrackResponse[1]/*:` in the `xpath`

```
--Results: X

declare @xmlTable as table (
 xmlData xml
)
insert into @xmlTable 
select '<TrackResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
             <Response xmlns="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
              ...
        </TrackResponse>'

;with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0')
select
  x.xmlData.value('(/*:TrackResponse[1]/*:Shipment[1]/Package[1]/Activity[1]/Status[1]/Type[1])','varchar(100)') as all_snacks
from @xmlTable x
```